# Consume a Web Service from R with XML structure

Tags: r, database, wsdl

I would like to consume the information from a Web Service in R, but I don't know how to get the data.

I can do  an excellent way with the connection of the WS through R:

```
url <-"https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500"

username <- "XXX"
password <- "YYY"

MH_1 <- GET(url,
            authenticate(username,password, type = "basic"))
MH_1 

Response [https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500]
  Date: 2021-11-02 10:10
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Size: 22.7 kB
```

I successfully connect to the WS from R, I have a 200 in Status.

Then I can see the content of the WS:

```
> content(MH_1)
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
{xml_document}
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
 [1] <wsdl:documentation>\n  <sidl:sidl xmlns:sidl="http://www.sap.com/2007/03/sidl"/>\n</wsdl:documentation>
 [2] <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
 [3] <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN__binding">\n  <wsp:ExactlyOne>\n    <wsp:All>\n      <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">false</sapattahnd:Enabled>\n      <saptrnbn ...
 [4] <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN__binding_soap12">\n  <wsp:ExactlyOne>\n    <wsp:All>\n      <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">false</sapattahnd:Enabled>\n      <s ...
 [5] <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IF__ZFMG_REPORTS">\n  <wsp:ExactlyOne>\n    <wsp:All>\n      <sapsession:Session xmlns:sapsession="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/session/">\n        <sapsession:enableSe ...
 [6] <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP__ZwsYMhd76000042">\n  <wsp:ExactlyOne>\n    <wsp:All>\n      <saptrhnw05:required xmlns:saptrhnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/transaction/">no</saptrhnw05:required>\n  ...
 [7] <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP__ZwsZfmMensual">\n  <wsp:ExactlyOne>\n    <wsp:All>\n      <saptrhnw05:required xmlns:saptrhnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/transaction/">no</saptrhnw05:required>\n    ...
 [8] <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP__ZwsZinforme37New">\n  <wsp:ExactlyOne>\n    <wsp:All>\n      <saptrhnw05:required xmlns:saptrhnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/transaction/">no</saptrhnw05:required>\n ...
 [9] <wsdl:types>\n  <xsd:schema xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">\n    <xsd:simpleType name="char1 ...
[10] <wsdl:message name="ZwsYMhd76000042">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZwsYMhd76000042"/>\n</wsdl:message>
[11] <wsdl:message name="ZwsYMhd76000042Response">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:ZwsYMhd76000042Response"/>\n</wsdl:message>
[12] <wsdl:message name="ZwsZfmMensual">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZwsZfmMensual"/>\n</wsdl:message>
[13] <wsdl:message name="ZwsZfmMensualResponse">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:ZwsZfmMensualResponse"/>\n</wsdl:message>
[14] <wsdl:message name="ZwsZinforme37New">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZwsZinforme37New"/>\n</wsdl:message>
[15] <wsdl:message name="ZwsZinforme37NewResponse">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:ZwsZinforme37NewResponse"/>\n</wsdl:message>
[16] <wsdl:portType name="ZFMG_REPORTS">\n  <wsdl:documentation>\n    <sapdoc:sapdoc xmlns:sapdoc="urn:sap:esi:documentation">\n      <sapdoc:docitem docURL="http://APP-SIGAF4.mh.hacienda.go.cr:8000/sap/bc/e ...
[17] <wsdl:binding name="binding" type="tns:ZFMG_REPORTS">\n  <wsp:Policy>\n    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BN__binding"/>\n  </wsp:Policy>\n  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" st ...
[18] <wsdl:binding name="binding_soap12" type="tns:ZFMG_REPORTS">\n  <wsp:Policy>\n    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BN__binding_soap12"/>\n  </wsp:Policy>\n  <wsoap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap. ...
[19] <wsdl:service name="ZFMG_REPORTS">\n  <wsdl:port name="binding" binding="tns:binding">\n    <soap:address location="http://APP-SIGAF4.mh.hacienda.go.cr:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_repo ...
>
```

I need the information from lines [11], [13], [15], which are data files with the information I need.

The problem is that I don't know how to access this information.

I can make the connection to the WS correctly, but I don't know how to access and get the data, which are the queries of the aforementioned lines.

It is a SOAP WS, and the information is in an XML structure.

Someone could help me, please.

Comment: You can extract information easily from xml using the `xml2` package. Since your example is not reproducible (we cannot access the xml ourselves because it requires authentication), all I can suggest is that you read about how to navigate an xml document using the package vignettes.

Comment: This is the code to be able to access:
`
url <-"https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500"
username <- "Ws_cgr"
password <- "Claves+2021"
MH_1 <- GET(url,
            authenticate(username,password, type = "basic"))
`

I had tried something similar before,  with `xml_text ()` or `xml_attr ()` functions.
May you please show me a possible case of extraction from one of the 3 queries.
I've been thinking about it but I can't get to any of the data files.

Thanks!

Comment: Oscar, it's not clear what information you want from these nodes: there isn't any data or file names in them. I can access them using xml2, but it's not clear what you are actually looking for out of them

Comment: Hi Allan!  Do you know SoapUI software?

I can access to the WS and the data through the SOAPui. I must put certain parameters  get the desired query.

The problem is that in R, I can access the WS, but neither do you enter the parameters, nor the data.

In R that could be possible?

Answer (score 0):

As Allan points out in the comments, the `xml2` package is specifically designed to parse XML in R. It looks like you're interested in the lines with name attributes containing "Response", so here's some code that will extract those XML nodes:

```
xpath_string <- "//wsdl:message[contains(@name, 'Response')]"
xml2::xml_find_all(content(MH_1), xpath_string)
```

```
{xml_nodeset}
[1] <wsdl:message name="ZwsYMhd76000042Response">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:ZwsYMhd76000042Response"/>\n</wsdl:message>
[2] <wsdl:message name="ZwsZfmMensualResponse">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:ZwsZfmMensualResponse"/>\n</wsdl:message>
[3] <wsdl:message name="ZwsZinforme37NewResponse">\n  <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:ZwsZinforme37NewResponse"/>\n</wsdl:message>
```

which returns a nodeset, so you'll likely need to extract further information with `xml_text()` or `xml_attr()`

Comment: This is the code to be able to access:
`
url <-"https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500"
username <- "Ws_cgr"
password <- "Claves+2021"
MH_1 <- GET(url,
            authenticate(username,password, type = "basic"))
`
I had tried something similar before,  with `xml_text ()` or `xml_attr ()` functions, with no luck.
May you please show me a possible case of extraction from one of the 3 queries.
I've been thinking about it but I can't get to any of the data files.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see data files in any of the nodes you've provided, nor when I go to the website above in my browser and log in manually.  You're expecting to get links to data files this way?

Comment: Hi Dubukay!  Do you know SoapUI software?

I can access to the WS and the data through the SOAPui. I must put certain parameters  get the desired query.

The problem is that in R, I can access the WS, but neither do you enter the parameters, nor the data.

In R that could be possible?